# blackberry java webservice error

Tags: blackberry

i didnt get the output of the code.

```
HttpConnection httpConn;
httpConn = (HttpConnection)Connector.open("http://mydomainname.getsample.php?getData=mydata");
httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
int iResponseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
System.out.print(iResponseCode);
```

what is the error?. how i get the output ?
iam using blackberry simulator. on pc, the url retriving the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using eclipse

right click on the project->run as ->run configurations->simulator

check the option for launch mds with simulator.